# How to decide the ideal hold time in Ultimate Thread Group in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, threadgroup

How can we decide the ideal hold time in Ultimate Thrad Group in Jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal time depends on you use case but a total load time should last enough to be able to have a reliable analysis of your load test, at least 1 hour.

Comment: i am currently working on testing of the registration process of a website, what should be the ideal testplan for it to test how many concurrent registration it can handle.

i am fairly new to this testing scenario and learning

Comment: this is another very general question, that's not how stackoverflow works, at sO you must ask precise questions and if ok accept answer and upvote. Regarding your need first follow a jmeter tutorial there is a huge number just google for 1 you will be able to answer this new question.

Comment: Plz answer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005140/is-there-a-way-to-automate-jmeter-to-run-a-number-of-testplans

Comment: Please answer this too

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069561/how-to-see-the-usage-percentage-of-different-components-in-same-virtual-machine