# Is there a way to automate Jmeter to run a number of testplans

Tags: ant, automation, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Is there a way to automate Jmeter to run a number of test-plans?
Suppose I want to perform an experiment and run same test with single varying field one after the another, and reports saves for every test individually.

For example: perform a number of tests by varying the ramp-up time 
so that I start it once and leave its for hours
and comeback to see the whole experiment is performed.
I read somewhere that ANT can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd extract relevant variables to .properties files and execute tests passing different cfg file name every time. Jmeter.properties, user.properties, system.properties and similar are what you are looking for.